# How can I manually add login credentials through the Windows Credential Manager?

Tags: windows, credentials

For example I'd like to add the Steam login credentials, since the browsers won't ask to save the password. Is there a way to do it manually?

If I choose to add a new windows credentials and put in the url form: store.steampowered.com and then my Username and Password it won't show up anyway during the login.

Is there a way to do something similar for App logins (e.g Steam client)?

Answer (score 0):

Go to step 4 of this:  http://windows.microsoft.com/en-us/windows7/store-passwords-certificates-and-other-credentials-for-automatic-logon

Enter a DNS name (store.steampowered.com) along with the credentials and it should work.

**Please note (and in your question you even state this) that this won't work the same way that a password manager such as LastPass would work; there are more autofill and autologin functions associated with a password manager than there are with Credential Manager.**

Let me know if this isn't what you're looking for, thanks.

Comment: Sorry if I've been unclear, but this is exactly what I tried before, but it doesn't work

Comment: At this point, then you've exhausted everything you can do from a Credential Manager standpoint.  It wasn't designed with the use in mind that you're referring to.  Sorry my friend.

Comment: Yeah.. I'm also reading that it isn't very secure either so I better dump it for Lastpass

Comment: Yeah, it really isn't the most secure of mechanisms as someone with admin privs on the Windows box could manipulate it pretty easily if they knew what they were doing.